# Show/hide history index in console

Tags: command-history, prompt, suse

Via Putty, i log onto a SuSe linux machine.

Suddenly, a percentage value appeared behind the commandline. Looks like that:

```
[<DOMAIN>\<USER>@<HOST>:/home] 544%
```

It seems the value is the current index of the command in `history`. How can i remove that? How have i have activated that?

Edit:

```
PS1='[\u@\h:\w] \!% '
```

By removing \! in $HOME/.profile PS1 it can be switched off. It seems I copied it by accident from an tutorial when changing environment variables.

Comment: could you post the output from `echo "$PS1"` ?

Comment: Look through the files that Tim notes below, and remove the `\!` text from the PS1 variable assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify your prompt.  In Bash, which is the default shell for most Linux distributions, it can be set for Interactive Logins in `/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.bashrc`, `$OHME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.bash_login`, or `$HOME/.profile`.  That's the order those files are loaded, so a definition in `$HOME/.profile` will override any earlier definitions.

So, if you wanted to keep mostly the same format, just without the history index, you could add to your `$HOME/.profile`, something like (assuming the DOMAIN is being added to your environment as `$domain` via SSSD:

```
PS1='[$domain\\\u@\h:\w]% `
export PS1
```

That would give you a prompt that would look like:

```
[<DOMAIN>\<USER>@<HOST>:~]%
```

For more info on setting your prompt [read this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html).